# How to prove if $P(A) = P(B) \cap P(C)$ then $A = B \cap C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given three sets $A,B,C$

please help me to prove that if $P(A) = P(B) \cap P(C)$ then $A = B \cap C$

Comment: I meant Power-set  i.e P({1,2}) = { {}, {1}, {2}, {1,2} }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is an elementary proof.
\begin{align}
&x\in B\cap C\\
\implies& x\in B \ \ \&\ \ x\in C\\
\implies& \{x\}\in P(B)\ \ \&\ \ \{x\}\in P(C)\\
\implies& \{x\}\in P(B)\cap P(C)\\
\implies& \{x\}\in P(A)\\
\implies& x\in A
\end{align}
Hence, $B\cap C\subset A$
The other side is exactly similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, you just made my day

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pathway to a solution. First prove the following two facts:

- If $X$ is a set, then $\bigcup \mathcal{P}(X) = X$.
- If $X$ and $Y$ are sets, then $\mathcal{P}(X) \cap \mathcal{P}(Y) = \mathcal{P}(X \cap Y)$

Then piece these two facts together to obtain the proof of the result in your question.

[In case the notation is unfamiliar to you: we have $\bigcup \mathcal{F} = \bigcup_{U \in \mathcal{F}} U = \{ x \mid x \in U \text{ for some } U \in \mathcal{F} \}$.]

Comment: Im sorry this made me only more confused, I cannot understand what I'm reading ( except the second bullet.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to prove the following elementary facts:

1) for any sets $A, B$ one has $\mathscr{P}(A) \cap \mathscr{P}(B)=\mathscr{P}(A \cap B)$.

2) for any sets $A, B$ one has
$$A \subseteq B \Longleftrightarrow \mathscr{P}(A) \subseteq \mathscr{P}(B)$$
and consequently 
$$A=B \Longleftrightarrow \mathscr{P}(A)=\mathscr{P}(B)$$ 
which follows straight away from the **axiom of extensionality**.

With this you will have completely solved the problem.

Keep in mind the more general relation
$$\bigcap_{i \in I}\mathscr{P}(A_i)=\mathscr{P}(\bigcap_{i \in I}A_i)$$
valid for any family $A$ of sets indexed by an arbitrary nonempty index set $I$.

Comment: Thanks I haven't learned axioms yet but this will be very useful for later

Comment: @Patent Lobster: one should not even begin to get engaged in serious and proper mathematics before one acquires at least a fair degree of familiarity with the axioms and the structure of the formal-deductive language which expresses mathematics.

Comment: I study in the university and this is my first course which there I will I acquire a fair degree of familiarity with all of what you just said :) right now we are at the basics which I still struggle with.

Comment: @PatentLobster I see. My remark was not in any way meant as a personal criticism to you, if anything what is at times to be decried is how the curricula of various universities does not properly manage to guide the students towards a firm assimilation of the axiomatic foundations. Someone should have presented you with at least a modicum of axiomatics before even inviting you to solve such exercises.